# Как разрешить кросс-доменное подключение к серверу веб сокетов?

Tags: java, spring, websocket, cross-domain, sockjs

Использую Spring для написания API сервиса. Возникла необходимость в вебсокетах для реализации прогресс бара и уведомлений. API крутится на порту 8080 (default), а сама веб-морда соответственно на 80. Для подключения использую SockJS и STOMP. Все делаю по этому тутору http://spring-projects.ru/guides/messaging-stomp-websocket/ Собственно вопрос: как разрешить клиентам с других доменов подключаться? И есть ли возможность ограничить такие домены?

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите информацию по поводу настройки кросс-ориджина в спринге. Должно помочь.

В частности либо

```
    @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:9000")
    @RequestMapping("/greeting")
public String Greeting greeting() {
    System.out.println("==== in greeting ====");
    return "wow, cross-origin string!";
}
```

либо в случае настройки для всего приложения

```
@Bean
public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
    return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
            registry.addMapping("/greeting-javaconfig").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:9000");
        }
    };
}
```

Подробней можно глянуть [тут](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/)